# Setup team or users permissions with VSTS REST API

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to setup the teams or users permissions via the VSTS Rest API ?

I've only found posts that are quite old and without any update on the subject. 
On the API page it seems like it would be possible to remove them for users or groups but not list the permissions for a specific user or add some.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/security/permissions/remove%20permission?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Did you ever find a way to list the permissions for a user or group?

Comment: Hi, yes I was able to do it. I used this [github project](https://github.com/jelledruyts/TfsTeamProjectManager) as a base, since the TFS and VSTS APIs are very close. I'm not sure it is up to date though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API is not documented, however you can track it by tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome browser then select `Network`.

e.g. I can use below REST API To set the `Delete team project` permission to `Allow` for my team `Team0416` in below sample:

```
POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{Project}/_api/_security/ManagePermissions?__v=5
```

Request body:

```
{"updatePackage":"{\"IsRemovingIdentity\":false,\"TeamFoundationId\":\"18de9da7-7edc-4c1d-88e0-e2420020e6dd\",\"DescriptorIdentityType\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity\",\"DescriptorIdentifier\":\"S-1-9-1551374245-717605811-4129483085-2927145651-87449592-1-853620709-4198499904-2869176592-1434840851\",\"PermissionSetId\":\"52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819\",\"PermissionSetToken\":\"vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/b3cbc52a-22f6-4de9-ae78-b2b305365ff8\",\"RefreshIdentities\":false,\"Updates\":[{\"PermissionId\":1,\"PermissionBit\":4,\"NamespaceId\":\"52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819\",\"Token\":\"$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/b3cbc52a-22f6-4de9-ae78-b2b305365ff8:\"}],\"TokenDisplayName\":null}"}
```

> **The key points:**
>
> *"Updates\":[{\"PermissionId\"*:**1**, in the request body:
>
> --> **0** means `Not set`,**1** means `Allow`, **2** means **Deny**

Besides, you can use [Permission Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/permission-command?view=vsts) to modify the user access control list (ACL) and displays authorization settings for an item under version control.

And you can use the [TFSSecurity command-line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) to create, modify, and delete groups and users in TFS, in addition to modifying permissions for groups and users.

[image]